# Why does Scala compilation get stuck in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) 13.1.3 and am trying to compile a Scala 2.10.4 project. It compiles for a while, then the compile process hangs.

I can compile and run my project from the sbt console.

I already invalidated caches, cleaned the project, reinstalled IntelliJ IDEA and all plugins.

Any ideas why Intellij behaves like this?

Comment: Restart IntelliJ? restart machine? anything in event log? cpu high or low?

Comment: How big is your project? Mine has around 50 classes and it doesn't hang up, it takes 3 or 4 minutes though which is much longer than compiling it with the console.

Comment: I'm experiencing it, too and guess it's a sort of a bug in IDEA. I'm working with the latest build and sbt on the command line is the only rescue so far. I can't wait till they fix that.

Comment: The project has around 1000 files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Play Framework plugin. Uninstalling it did the trick.

Alternatively, you can try the Community Edition, as it does not have Play support at all.